# Displaying value based on selected value in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following data

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = [{"city":"New York","location":"123", "sales" :"233.00"},
                {"city":"Chicago","location":"953", "sales":"455"}'
                {"city":"New York","location":"788",  "sales" :"23432.23"},
                {"city":"Chicago","location":"853"}];

  $scope.update=function(location){

  };
}]);
```

In my html I have

```
  <td>
    <select ng-model="item.location" ng-options="c.location as c.city for c in data" 
     ng-change="update(c.location)"></select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <span ng-model="item.sales">{{sales }} </span>
    </div>
  </td>
```

I am trying to call update function from selected value of drop down and based on the item selected I want to update the value of sale using span. I am not sure how to accomplish that part. Please let me know how to go about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need your update function, just use data-binding. Change your ng-options like this to bind the whole object instead of just a field `location` :

```
ng-options="c as c.city for c in data"
```

To display the sales, just do this:

```
<span>{{ item.location.sales }} </span>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/b5Q6AxgZyqT9rL9IPA9j?p=preview)